# How to match data in two columns (lat/long) to closest values in two other columns?

Tags: r

I have a list of known lat/long coordinates, and I need to locate these within a lat/long grid and pull out the adjacent data.  My known lat/long coordinates are in a dataframe like:

```
LatLong <- structure(list(Lat_orig = c(-55.417, -55.417, -55.417, -55.417, 
-55.417), Long_orig = c(-69.58, -69.249, -69.0831, -69.417, -69.749
), Lat_new = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Long_new = c(NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA), Jan = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Feb = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA), Mar = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Apr = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
May = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Jun = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
Jul = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Aug = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
Sep = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Oct = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
Nov = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Dec = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("Lat_orig", 
"Long_orig", "Lat_grid", "Long_grid", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", 
"May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))



    Lat_orig    Long_orig   Lat_grid    Long_grid   Jan Feb Mar Apr May  Jun    Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
-55.417 -69.5800    NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
-55.417 -69.2490    NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
-55.417 -69.0831    NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
-55.417 -69.4170    NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
-55.417 -69.7490    NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

I have a second dataframe that contains a gridded global dataset.  It's very large, but here is a small chunk:

```
Grid <- structure(list(lat = c(-55.417, -55.417, -55.417, -55.417, -55.417
), long = c(-69.75, -69.583, -69.417, -69.25, -69.083), jan = c(8.5, 
8.5, 8.4, 8.7, 8.8), feb = c(8.4, 8.5, 8.3, 8.6, 8.8), mar = c(7.3, 
7.3, 7.2, 7.5, 7.6), apr = c(5.8, 5.8, 5.7, 5.9, 6), may = c(4, 
3.9, 3.7, 4, 4), jun = c(2.7, 2.7, 2.4, 2.7, 2.7), jul = c(2.2, 
2.2, 2, 2.2, 2.3), aug = c(2.6, 2.6, 2.4, 2.7, 2.8), sep = c(3.8, 
3.9, 3.7, 4, 4.1), oct = c(5.5, 5.5, 5.3, 5.7, 5.8), nov = c(6.6, 
6.7, 6.5, 6.9, 7), dec = c(7.9, 7.9, 7.7, 8.1, 8.2)), .Names = c("lat", 
"long", "jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "may", "jun", "jul", "aug", 
"sep", "oct", "nov", "dec"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))



    lat long    jan feb mar apr may jun jul aug sep oct nov dec
-55.417 -69.750 8.5 8.4 7.3 5.8 4.0 2.7 2.2 2.6 3.8 5.5 6.6 7.9
-55.417 -69.583 8.5 8.5 7.3 5.8 3.9 2.7 2.2 2.6 3.9 5.5 6.7 7.9
-55.417 -69.417 8.4 8.3 7.2 5.7 3.7 2.4 2.0 2.4 3.7 5.3 6.5 7.7
-55.417 -69.250 8.7 8.6 7.5 5.9 4.0 2.7 2.2 2.7 4.0 5.7 6.9 8.1
-55.417 -69.083 8.8 8.8 7.6 6.0 4.0 2.7 2.3 2.8 4.1 5.8 7.0 8.2
```

I need to locate each lat/long coordinate of `LatLong` in `Grid`, and then pull the adjacent data from `Grid` columns `jan` to `dec` and put these into the appropriate columns in dataframe `LatLong`. When I do this manually, I first locate the nearest latitude, and then look in the associated longitudes to find the closest match. This would give me a solution like this:

```
Lat_orig    Long_orig   Lat_grid    Long_grid   Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
-55.417 -69.58  -55.417 -69.583 8.5 8.5 7.3 5.8 3.9 2.7 2.2 2.6 3.9 5.5 6.7 7.9
-55.417 -69.249 -55.417 -69.25  8.7 8.6 7.5 5.9 4   2.7 2.2 2.7 4   5.7 6.9 8.1
-55.417 -69.0831    -55.417 -69.083 8.8 8.8 7.6 6   4   2.7 2.3 2.8 4.1 5.8 7   8.2
-55.417 -69.417 -55.417 -69.417 8.4 8.3 7.2 5.7 3.7 2.4 2   2.4 3.7 5.3 6.5 7.7
-55.417 -69.749 -55.417 -69.75  8.5 8.4 7.3 5.8 4   2.7 2.2 2.6 3.8 5.5 6.6 7.9
```

Note that in my example, all of the Latitude values are constant, but these also vary in both dataframes.

Does anyone know the best way to do this? I've tried using `gdist` from the package `Imap`, and I can find the nearest point but only for a single coordinate at a time! Does anyone know a good way to locate these points and move this data to the new dataframe?

Comment: If it's a grid (cross product of a list of latitudes and a list of longitudes), you can use `findInterval` to find the square in the grid that the point falls in. Isolate the 4 lat-long pairs. Then find the closest point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generalized question, one-dimensional:

Given a set of sample points and a set of reference points, how do I map a point to its closest reference point?

Let's generate some points and reference points.

```
set.seed(100)
pp <- sample(0:100, 10, replace = FALSE)
# [1] 31 25 54  5 45 46 77 34 50 15
rr <- sort(sample(0:100, 10, replace = FALSE))
# [1]  19  27  33  39  63  64  73  88  93 100
```

Using `findInterval` and midpoints:

```
## finds midpoints between reference points
midpoints <- head(rr,-1) + diff(rr)/2
# [1] 23.0 30.0 36.0 51.0 63.5 68.5 80.5 90.5 96.5
## determines which reference interval each sample point falls into
intv <- findInterval(pp, midpoints)
# [1] 2 1 4 0 3 3 6 2 3 0
## index back into reference point to find closest reference point
rr[intv+1]
# [1] 33 27 63 19 39 39 73 33 39 19
```

Do this for both your latitudes and your longitudes, and you can find the proper points.

To pull the remaining recorded data, use a `merge` though beware floating-point error).

Comment: Thanks Blue Magister! This does seem to work OK for my Lats, but I get an error for Long ('vec' must be sorted non-decreasingly). I used Long_sorted <- sort(Grid$long) and tried again, but it seems to still assign the incorrect points. I will continue trying but please let me know if you see what i'm doing wrong!  thanks!

Comment: Possibly using `sort(unique(Grid$long))` as your reference points may help, but I can't tell for sure without looking at the code or original data.